# BitLocker fails to initialize after relocating BDEDrive

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I'm trying to create an additional partition om my notebook by shrinking the C: partition (Windows 7).
In order to achieve this, the following steps are applied:

1. Disable BitLocker and decrypt C: data.
2. Apply "chkdsk /f" as many times as needed, until all disk errors are fixed.
3. Shrink C: partition using built-in Disk Management utility. At this point I can still start BitLocker and encrypt the C: data (it has been **verified** by doing).
4. Move BDEDrive adjacent to C: partition (using gparted live utility). After this operation BitLocker fails to initialize. The following message is displayed:

> The path specified in the Boot Configuration Data (BCD) for a BitLocker Drive Encription integrity-protected application is incorrect. Please verify and correct your BCD settings and try again.

Step no. 3) is necessary because there is unused space behind the BDEDrive that I would like to utilize. By the way, moving BDEDrive to the very end of the HDD gives the same result.

Only possible way to start the BitLocker again is to move the BDEDrive back to its original position (this is also **verified and confirmed**). It is good to know that the procedure is reversible.

Still I did not achieve the goal, which is to make a single continuous space for an additional partition. I hope someone knows how to do the final step no. 5)

**How to enter the correct BCD settings?**

P.S. Removing BDEDrive is not an option, because BitLocker encryption is mandated by my employer.

Answer (score 2):

I have found how to do this the right way.
Step 4) is not needed at all. The whole trick is to remove the BDEDrive partition, so next time BitLocker is started it will make a new one, which is of course adjacent to the existing C: partition.

In case anyone else needs to do this, here is the whole procedure step by step:

1. Disable BitLocker and decrypt C: data
2. Apply "chkdsk /f" as many times as needed, until all disk errors are fixed
3. Shrink C: partition using built-in Disk Management utility
4. Apply (as admin) "bcdboot c:\windows /s c:" to copy system files on C: partition
5. Set C: partition to Active using built-in Disk Management utility, and reboot
6. Remove BDEDrive partition using built-in Disk Management utility, and reboot
7. Start BitLocker and follow the steps, which are self explanatory

BitLocker is going to create a new BDEDrive partition, ask you to Save the recovery key, Run BitLocker system check, and Encrypt C: partition.

After all these steps are completed your disk layout will look as follows

- Windows 7 - X GB, Boot, Encrypted, C:
- BDEDrive - 300 MB, System, Active, no drive letter
- Unallocated - Y GB

Comment: If this solves your problem you can and should mark your answer as accepted :)